# Apostrophe terminates string, causes script to not work

Tags: javascript, tumblr, blogger

I've written the following script, which I'm using on my website (http://www.xeasycorex.net) for a Tumblr button that sits in each post. The `strPostTitle.replace` line escapes any quotes, but I need to do the same for apostrophes as it's terminating the string when present in post titles and not displaying the button, I'm just not sure how to do this.

For example, the Tumblr button is currently missing from the first post (http://www.xeasycorex.net/2013/05/liotta-and-mays-landing-announce-mini.html).

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
var strPostUrl = "<data:post.url/>";
var strPostTitle = '<data:post.title/>';
var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace("http://","");
var strNewTitle = strPostTitle.replace(/"/g, '"');
document.write("<a href='http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url="+strNewUrl+"&name="+strNewTitle+"'><img src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Vw74mICSigg/USjO29GAujI/AAAAAAAARHE/dY0nzXtwTVU/s81/tumblr-share.png'/></a>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `encodeURIComponent` instead. It converts your apostrophes to their url equivalents and makes sure you don't run into any trouble.

I'm not sure whether you're supposed to use single or double apostrophes here: `"<data:post.url/>"` and `'<data:post.title/>'`, you should make sure that either both are supported or you are using the right one.

Comment: I've heard of it before, but couldn't get it working. How could I implement it into my script? Thanks

Comment: `var strPostUrl = encodeURIComponent(...), strPostTitle = encodeURIComponent(...);`

Comment: I tried adding that line, but all the buttons stopped working. I wrote the script a while ago and can't remember exactly why I alternated between apostrophes and quotes, but if I used either on both, the button wouldn't work

Comment: I also just noticed that if I use quotes/double-apostrophes on `'<data:post.title/>'`, the button loads, but the post title gets cut off just before where the apostrophe is

Comment: Could you check what html code (or js for that matter) this compiles into?

Comment: Now I remember.. If I use quotes on `<data:post.title/>`, the button doesn't appear on posts with quotes in the title. If I use apostrophes on `<data:post.title/>`, the button doesn't appear on posts with apostrophes in the title. I need a method to escape quotes and apostrophes in the title

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that